# How to package a sequence functions that act on parameter in order in Python

Tags: python, function, first-class

Imagine there are three functions, all them accept and return  the same type args.

Normally, we can write it as `fun3(fun2(fun1(args))`, this can be say that a sequence function act on parameter in order, which likes one variety Higher-order functions "map".

You know in Mathematica, we can write this as `fun3@fun2@fun1@args`.

Now the question is that can we integrate fun3@fun2@fun1  as another fun without modifying their definition, so `fun(args)` can replace `fun3(fun2(fun1(args))`,  this looks more elegant and concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def merge_steps(*fun_list):
    def fun(arg):
        result = arg
        for f in fun_list:
            result = f(result)
        return result

    return fun


def plus_one(arg):
    return arg + 1


def double_it(arg):
    return arg ** 2


def power_ten(arg):
    return arg ** 10


combine1 = merge_steps(power_ten, plus_one, double_it)
combine2 = merge_steps(plus_one, power_ten, double_it)

combine1(3) 
> 3486902500
```

or use lambda:

```
steps = [power_ten, plus_one, double_it]

reduce(lambda a, f: f(a), steps, 3)
> 3486902500
```

Comment: really cool , it is my ideal ,especially that the combine of lambda and reduce suits me, it is a chip off the mathematica " f@@expr or Apply[f,expr] " like  f2@f1@t gives f2[f1[t]] , without define a function . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Function Recursion in python to do this.

```
def function(args, times):
    print(f"{times} Times - {args}")
    if times > 0 : 
        function(args,times - 1)

function("test", 2)
```

*Note: I just add times argument to not generate infinite loop.*

Comment: it gives me that  it goes far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I understand your question, but are you talking about function composition along these lines?

```
# Some single-argument functions to experiment with.

def double(x):
    return 2 * x

def reciprocal(x):
    return 1 / x

# Returns a new function that will execute multiple single-argument functions in order.

def compose(*funcs):
    def g(x):
        for f in funcs:
            x = f(x)
        return x
    return g

# Demo.

double_recip_abs = compose(double, reciprocal, abs)
print(double_recip_abs(-2))   # 0.25
print(double_recip_abs(.1))   # 5.0
```

Comment: it works also, but it doesn't  seperate the new function generation and its  parameter call , 'compose' returns the final result , not the new function。

Comment: @eason OK, now I think I understand your goal. See edited answer.

Comment: absolutely,  the use of closures, it hit me, but I am an introductory python er.